# Spark sql create dataset from string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a String from which i would like to create a dataset, the string is `\n` separated for lines and `\t` separated for the fields:
`8  "SOMETHING" 15236236    "2" "SOMETHING" "SOMETHHING"`

So i split the string by `\n` and create a `List<String>` out of it, then i create a JavaRDD using a JavaSparkContext instance, then i try to create my Dataset by using the sqlContet method `createDataset`.
This compiles fine, and if i put a breakpoint at the return statement of the loadDataset() method, i see the `settingsDataset` dataset, it only breaks after the code invokes a the first action.

The way i am trying to chieve this is:

```
private Dataset<Row> loadDataset(){
    InputStream in;
    Dataset<Row> settingsDataset = null;
    try {
      JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkConte xt(session.sparkContext());
      in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename.tsv");
      String settingsFileAsString = IOUtils.toString(in, Charsets.UTF_8);
      List<String> settingsFileAsList = Arrays.asList(settingsFileAsString.split("\n"));
      Encoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(getSchema());
      JavaRDD settingsFileAsRDD = jsc.parallelize(settingsFileAsList);
      settingsDataset = session.sqlContext().createDataset(settingsFileAsRDD.rdd(), encoder).toDF();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return settingsDataset;
 }

  private org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType getSchema() {
    return DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
        DataTypes.createStructField("f_1", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f_2", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f_3", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f_4", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f_5", DataTypes.StringType, true),
        DataTypes.createStructField("f_6", DataTypes.StringType, true)
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the DAG wont be created, the code breaks with the following exception:
`! java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real `JavaRDD settingsFileAsRDD = jsc.parallelize(settingsFileAsList);` is `JavaRDD<String>` but it should be `JavaRDD<Row>`. You should split these "lines" by `\t` and create new `Row` out of it using `RowFactory.create(s.split("\t"))`. See example below:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
String settingsFileAsString = "1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\n7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12";
List<String> settingsFileAsList = Arrays.asList(settingsFileAsString.split("\n"));
Encoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(getSchema());
JavaRDD<Row> settingsFileAsRDD = jsc.parallelize(settingsFileAsList).map(s->RowFactory.create(s.split("\t")));
Dataset<Row> settingsDataset = spark.createDataset(settingsFileAsRDD.rdd(), encoder).toDF();
settingsDataset.show();
```

result:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|f_1|f_2|f_3|f_4|f_5|f_6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11| 12|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```